# How to tell who called an HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

How can I tell from within an ASP.NET HttpHandler if it is executing because of a call to

```
Server.Execute("myHandler.ashx")
```

or because of the user linking directly to `myHandler.ashx`? (Besides using a querystring parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you add a querystring parameter? If present comes from Server.Execute(), otherwise direct link.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing right now. I'm wondering if there is something else I can get from the HttpContext that will tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You should still have access to the HttpContext from within the handler, so you should still be able to access cookies and session to determine any authenticated users (if that's what you're looking for).

Comment: In both cases the user will be authenticated on the site.

Comment: @Chris Dwyer - right, so you should have access to all of that information from within the handler.

Comment: what should I check in the Request that would tell me what I need to know?

Comment: @Chris Dwyer - If you're using formsauthentication with cookies, you could use HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["YourCookieName"] to grab their cookie data and unencrypt/read their FormsauthenticationTicket.